# Tensorflow max_gradient_norm parameter in Seq2Seq

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying out seq2seq in Tensorflow. 
In seq2seq there's a parameter named `max_gradient_norm`.
As per I understand, this parameter clips the gradient when it's norm is more than `max_gradient_norm`.

My question is on what factors should I decide what should be the value for `max_gradient_norm` parameter ?